# Nginx: no response header

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, reverse-proxy

On my site (only on one url) there is no response header sent. I'm using Tamper Data, and the response block is full empty.
I'm using nginx az a reverese proxy with apache. Every other request goes ok, but this one not.

```
mysite.com/site/?page=logout
```

If I try with port 8080 (Apache) it goes well. But it's still strange that all the other pages get response header through nginx.

I can't imagine what can be the problem.

Comment: Look into error.log

Comment: Gone for a while... [26/Jan/2011:14:02:42 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3494 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; hu; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13" This is all, nothing related. Nothing in in error.log, this is access.log